# Wait for useCallback effects on DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm calling a `useCallback` from a `useEffect` that will make the component's height change. Then, to end the effect, I'd like to scroll the component to a specific point. The issue is that the scroll operation does not work because it fires to soon : the DOM did not update yet.

If I wrap it in a `setTimeout` it does work (because it fires once the DOM updated), but it's kind of hacky.

Is there a clean way to wait for the DOM to render before pursuing the effect?

**Does not work:**

```js
const viewportElement = useRef()
cont [innerHeight, setInnerHeight] = useState(0)

refreshDOM = useCallback(() => {
  setInnerHeight(500) // Will cause the DOM to refresh and the inner div to grow in height.
}, [setInnerHeight])

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  refreshDOM() // DOM updates
  viewportElement.current.scroll(0, 200) // Fires to soon: innerDiv is still too small 
}, [refreshDOM, someOtherStuffTriggeringTheEffect])

return (
  <div ref={viewportElement} style={{height: 100}}>
    <div style={{height: innerHeight}}></div>
  </div>
)
```

**Works:**

```js
// ...

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  refreshDOM() // DOM updates
  setTimeout(
    () => viewportElement.current && viewportElement.current.scroll(0, 200),
    0,
  ) // DOM was refreshed, scroll operation works
}, [refreshDOM, someOtherStuffTriggeringTheEffect])

// ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is add the another `useEffect` and pass to dependencies `innerHeight`. When `innerHeight` is updated it means that you can invoke scrolling:

```
useEffect(() => {
  viewportElement.current.scroll(0, 200)
}, [innerHeight]);
```

And don't forget to remove scrolling from `useLayoutEffect`

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to [Rukkiesman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10705034/rukkiesman) answer

The reason it's not working is cause, setting the height is `async`. Which means the height hasn't been updated at the time you called `viewportElement.current.scroll(0, 200)`

The reason wrapping it in a `setTimeout` works, is cause you've add it to the micro task queue, which would resolve after react is done with the update work.